# Folder Appdata Unity and Visual Studio Community 2019 (For Unity) Can it be deleted?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, game-development

I uninstalled Unity & Visual Studio Community 2019 from my computer (C:\Program File).
But there are still folders on the computer. Can I delete it? I don't want these folders. Will there be problems later?

**Folder About Unity**

1. AppData\Roaming\Unity
2. AppData\Roaming\UnityHub
3. AppData\Local\Unity
4. AppData\Local\Unity-Updater
5. AppData\LocalLow\Unity

**Foder About Visual Studio Community 2019 (For Unity)**

1. AppData\Roaming\Visual Studio Setup
2. AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
3. AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
4. AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services
5. C:\Program File (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio

In the future I may install Unity & Visual Studio Community again.
But I'm not sure if deleting these folders will cause the program to stop working

Comment: Yes, it will.  Why are you worried about this?  Disk space is practically free.

Comment: yes , I uninstalled the program. I just don't want irrelevant folders on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall unity completely. You can try the steps below. If you re-download the unity software, it is best to uninstall it completely.

```
       1. Clear the registry of unity.

         First, enter "regedit" in Run to open the registry interface.

         Delete all items under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Unity, including the Unity folder.

         Delete all items under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Unity Technologie, same as above.

       2. Clear temporary files. Maybe the paths are not exactly the same, just search for similar ones and delete them.

         C:\ProgramData\Unity (ProgramData folder may be hidden, show hidden files to view)

         C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Unity

         C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\LocalLow\Unity

         C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Unity
```